# Respository login error after starting the CRXDE Lite

Tags: aem

I am currently doing an authoring part in AEM where we only manage the content. Now I want to learn the creation of component and all the thing from the back end.
But I am facing one issue from a long time after installing the CRXDE Lite.
Can you please let me know what should my next step after downloading the CRXDE lite. from where I can download the CRX or CQ so that I can connect. or if I have buy so from where I can buy this.
Please help me with step by step guide. please see the screenshot below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Tjgs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRXDE is no longer supported. Adobe recommends using crxde lite which is web-based ide `http://localhost:4502/crx/de`. There are other IDE and/or plugins available to facilitate the development.

With eclipse you could use plugin like [vaultclipse](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/vaultclipse) or [Sling IDE tooling](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html) and in case you are a Idea IntelliJ user, you could use [intelliVault](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7328?pr=) or [Sling ide equivalent plugin for IntelliJ](https://github.com/headwirecom/aem-ide-tooling-4-intellij/wiki) by Headwire

Comment: How we can get the web based crxde lite? and how we can connect to cq/crx?

Comment: Web based CRXDELite comes packaged with product. Refer to Adobe's documentation @ https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/dev-tools/developing-with-crxde-lite.html .

Comment: Also you need to have the Quickstart jar and license file with you in order to get started.

Comment: Thanks for the information.
But I have tried to search and get this package download. but I didn't found this. Can you please let us know how we can get this package in our machine? if we have to buy from adobe so how we can buy?
and also the Quickstart jar and license file, from where we can get the files? please provide the URL as well.

Comment: Its not available publicly, you can reach out Adobe sales team for this. Just FYI, a single license costs fortune to buy personally. But always best to reach sales directly

Comment: Hi Ameesh,
Thank you for information and helping me with this.

Comment: Hi, I want to learn the component creation. but as you said the tool is not available publicly. so how we can learn or can do some practical things ?

Comment: Reach out to your IT leads or COE for this, your company if taking AEM development then you could reach out to those projects.. Entirely depends on your company processes.